# PropertyBag, type of class is showing in the editor, how to remove it?

Tags: c#-4.0

In the propertybag, for foo, I see WindowsApplication1.foo is shown and how do I show something meaningful text?

In the propertybag I see  Foo |windowsApplication1.foo. How can I change the windowsapplication1.foo to some meaningful text?
Thanks for the help.

```
static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Form form = new Form();
            PropertyGrid grid = new PropertyGrid();
            grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Controls.Add(grid);
            grid.SelectedObject = new MyType();
            Application.Run(form);


        }
    }

class MyType
{
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
    [CategoryAttribute("ID"), DescriptionAttribute("Id")]
    public Foo Foo
    {
        get { return foo; }
        set { }
    }
}

[Editor(typeof(FooEditor),typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]

class Foo
{
    private string bar;
    private string bar2;
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { bar = value; }
    }
    public string Bar2
    {
        get { return bar2; }
        set { bar2 = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the "propertybag" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the text, override `ToString()` in `Foo`, and you'll see that.

[Editor(typeof(FooEditor),typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]

```
class Foo
{
    // your implementation

    public override string ToString()
    {
         // Return what you want displayed...
         return string.Format("Foo: {0} - {1}", this.Bar, this.Bar2);
    }
}
```

If you want to make a better editor for `Foo`, you'll need to make a custom `UITypeEditor`.  For details, see [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic7) and [Make Your Components Really RAD with Visual Studio .NET Property Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302334.aspx).